# private init in C# props?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

What does `private` access modifier for [init only setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) in C# mean? I  usually make setter as private for most of the properties in my domain classes. With `init`, does it matter?

The following seem to work without any problem, the compiler does not complain.

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; private init; }
    public int Y { get; private init; }
}
```

So how is the above different from the below. There is not private below.

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; init; }
    public int Y { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: "The init accessor makes immutable objects more flexible by allowing the caller to mutate the members during the act of construction. That means the object's immutable properties can participate in object initializers and thus removes the need for all constructor boilerplate in the type". The question is very appropiate, as constructors are expected to be almost always `public`, except for the case of classes that contain only static members, where private constructor makes sense, same as private `init`s would I guess...

Comment: eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/4zxfkK

Comment: I came to this question because I was confused about the difference between `Prop { get; }` and `Prop {get; private init;}`. That's not exactly the OP's question, but that's what led me here. The difference is that, while get-only properties can only be set in the constructor, `private init` allows methods in the class to use the Property initialization syntax if they create objects of that class. Which might be useful if your constructor is private and you prefer using static methods for creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init` keyword was added in c# 9.0 in order to add immutable properties on objects.

The problem we used to have is that if you have this object you could still modify the Name property (although it has a private setter) via a public method. for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

And we also couldn't use object initializers

```
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Jane Doe" // Compile Error 
};
```

Now, if we change the code to use `init`

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

We are now able to use object initializers

```
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Jane Doe" // No error
};
```

But, if we use your `private init` like your example

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private init; }
}
```

We won't be able to use object initializers

```
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "Jane Doe" // Compile error
};
```

Comment: I miss a part of your answer where you say in what scenarios `private init` is useful and why it exists.

Answer (score 15):

It affects where the setter can be called from, just like normal setters.

Consider this code:

```cs
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; private init; }
    public int Y { get; private init; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var point = new Point { X = 10, Y = 20 };
    }
}
```

That fails with two compile-time errors:

> The property or indexer 'Point.X' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

(and the equivalent for `Y`).

The same initializer would be valid *in* the `Point` class, because the set accessors are accessible there. For example, you might want to use a public factory method, which is implemented with an object initializer:

```cs
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; private init; }
    public int Y { get; private init; }

    public static Point FromXY(int x, int y) =>
        new Point { X = x, Y = y };
}
```

(There are various reasons why that might not be ideal, or you might prefer to add parameters to a private constructor, but it's *an example* of where the private init-only setters are accessible.)

Likewise the code above would be valid without the `private` part of the set accessors, because then they can be called from anywhere (as part of an object initializer).

Comment: Then how to create object of `Point` with `private init`? What’s the practical use of `private init` over `init`?

Comment: @viveknuna: The practical use is if you want to use an object initializer to set properties, but only do so within the body of the same class declaration, as per my penultimate paragraph. For example, you might have several public static factory methods within the class, all of which use the object initializer for implementation.

Comment: classes with `static` members only @viveknuna, same case as for the class `private` constructors I guess, such as for the sigleton pattern

Comment: @rustyBucketBay: No, if there are only static members then there can't be any init-only properties anyway, as they only make sense for instance properties...

Comment: @JonSkeet didn’t get you, do you have any link to refer? Or if you could explain with some example.

Comment: @viveknuna: What *exactly* do you not understand? You can use the `private init` set accessor if you write an object initializer within the same class that declares the property. There are all kinds of reasons you might want to do that, but that's really outside the scope of the original question. (I'll put *an* example in the answer, but there are plenty of others...)